# Simple left join on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble building a query that would accomplish something relatively simple.

I have one table we can call `data`. This table has a `date` column and a column that specifies entries as `daily` data or `monthly` data.

I want to retrieve all `daily` records, along with `monthly` records in which no daily records exist in the month. Example: if daily record `2016-01-10` exists, then I do not want to retrieve monthly record on `2016-01-01`

I feel like this following query should be accomplishing this goal, but I cannot figure out why it's returning too many rows (duplicates) and when deduped, is not returning the desired set.

```
SELECT daily.* 
FROM data daily 
LEFT JOIN data monthly 
    ON date_trunc('month', daily.date) != date_trunc('month', monthly.date) 
AND monthly.interval='monthly' 
WHERE daily.interval='daily' 
    AND monthly.interval='monthly'
```

Intended behaviour is to return all records from the left, daily data, and join on the condition in which no monthly records are returned that have the same month as any daily records.

Comment: But the data in each table is the same, of course you're going to have records that match in both.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE you get regular inner join result.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from data d
where
    interval = 'daily'
    or
    interval = 'monthly'
    and
    not exists (
        select 1 from data
        where
            date_trunc('month', d.date) = date_trunc('month', date)
            and interval = 'daily'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following query and tell me if this works for you

```
SELECT monthly.* 
FROM data monthly 
 where monthly.interval='monthly' and to_char(monthly.date, 'YYYY-MM') not in 
(select to_char(daily.date, 'YYYY-MM') from data daily where daily.interval='daily' ) 
UNION
SELECT daily.* 
FROM data daily 
 where daily.interval='daily'
```

Comment: Thanks, editing the select statement to monthly.* works.

I changed the to_char to date_trunc and the query runs faster.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, but how do you actually compare that the month belongs to the same year?Do you write two date_trunc functions?

Comment: I believe using date_trunc actually selects the date at the beginning of whichever interval you choose. So using date_trunc('month', 2016-5-30) should return 2016-5-1

Comment: ok, thanks, at the moment I am using MySql and I could not test this function, thanks